# Why process physics before the variable framerate update in a game loop?

Tags: unity, physics, game-loop

As far as I know, most game loops are executed in the following order:

1. Process user input
2. Update (once per frame)
3. Physics (also known as `fixedUpdate`, 0 to N times per frame)
4. Rendering

You can find the execution order of the Unity game loop here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Unity's game loop is different in that `fixedUpdate` is executed earlier than `update`, is there any benefit to this when designing a game loop?

Additional information:
I'm not familiar with Unity, but I'm making a platformer game that mimics the execution order of Unity's game loop. I have found that if the update is later than physics, the rendering will lag significantly in responding to user input. If the physics fps is set lower (i.e. timestep is set higher), the lag is more significant. How does the Unity game solve this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think that we can answer this question. The only people who can answer this would be the people at Unity Technologies who made that architecture decision over a decade ago. And those are probably bound by NDAs. So we could only speculate. And speculative questions are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model.

Comment: I've never seen a game loop that works in the order you describe. Can you cite a source or evidence for the claim that "most" work in that order?

Comment: I've edited the question to focus on the more abstract "is there an advantage to processing the physics first?" in general, rather than specifically trying to read the minds of Unity's developers, which I think addresses the concern that Philipp raised while keeping the question focused on what OP wants to learn about.

Comment: @DMGregory Isn't the many times stated [fix your timestep](https://www.gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) similar to this?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I'd argue Glenn Fiedler shows processing the fixed timestep at the start of the game loop — place 2, or even place 1 since he doesn't check input in those examples. Then the framerate-variable part, interpolation, occurs after that. This would be analogous to Unity's order of doing things, opposite the order OP proposes. I was planning to cite Fiedler's example in an answer, in fact.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that renders current answers inapplicable after you've received answers. If what you really want to ask is "how to reduce latency using a fixed time step game loop" then ask that as a new question.

Comment: @DMGregory That's not the question I wanted to ask, I wanted to ask what exactly is the advantage of Unity's (bad) game loop. I implemented my own perfect game loop with physics and rendering separation, smooth movement with interpolation, absolutely better than Unity. I'm curious why people can put up with such obvious errors in Unity.

Comment: It sounds like you're basing this on the false premise that Unity forbids acting on new input within `FixedUpdate()`. Although you can certainly find a lot of wrong/outdated advice from gamedevs saying something vaguely like this, it's not at all true. You can configure Unity to capture input before `FixedUpdate` and respond to input there for minimum motion latency. You have to be careful to do it correctly of course, which may be why so many folks say not to - it's easy for a beginner to get it wrong, so they over-generalize "be careful" as "never".

Comment: @DMGregory Well ...... this seems more like hacking a Unity bug, because if Unity implemented the game loop correctly, it wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: You are welcome to believe that if you like. This site does not exist to validate your personal opinions about engines.

Comment: I've rolled back your most recent edit, "answering my own question". Answers belong in Answer posts, never in the question. You should also consult our [help center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which cautions against making posts where 'your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”'. "I have concluded [Engine X] is bad" is not a question.

Comment: @DMGregory Obviously, I stated that it was a current conclusion, and it was a "current" conclusion because I was waiting for a real meaningful answer from Unity users. Of course, Unity defenders are understandably irritated by my criticism (which you call a rant), and I would interpret that as the reason for your decision to roll back the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Executing the game logic after the physics and before rendering the frame allows the game logic to react to physics events before they are being rendered.

For example, when the physics engine moved an object into an area where it is supposed to be destroyed, then the game logic has the opportunity to destroy that object before it gets rendered in that invalid location.

Further, Unity is able to run the physics simulation with a much lower update rate than the FPS. In that case it offers the options to either interpolate or extrapolate rigidbody positions (which is a setting on [the Rigidbody component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html)) to smooth out the rendering of their motions. This smoothing happens before Update. So the Update method can access the interpolated/extrapolated object positions before the rendering happens. This is particularly important if you want to synchronize non-rigidbody objects with rigidbodies (e.g. `transform.position = followedObject.transform.position`). This needs to happen before rendering and with interpolated/extrapolated positions, or the objects won't be properly synchronized.

So by running the Unity Update-method just before the rendering guarantees that all the `transform.position`s  and `transform.rotation`s you check during it will actually be those which will appear on the screen...

...almost. There is still the animation system which runs before the rendering. The reason why the animation system gets processed after Update but before rendering is because you often want to set animation parameters in Update which you then want to be reflected in the current frame and not the next one.

But if you want to do something with the objects after the animation system was resolved, Unity still has you covered. You can use `LateUpdate` for that purpose.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, but I'm making a platformer game that mimics the execution order of Unity's game loop. I have found that if the update is later than physics, the rendering will lag significantly in responding to user input. If the physics fps is set lower (i.e. timestep is set higher), the lag is more significant. How does the Unity game solve this problem?

Comment: @BlackGlory What exactly does "processing user input" mean to you? In Unity, "user input processing" just means to set a bunch of flags on the "Input" class. The reaction to those flags ("if space button is pressed, jump") can happen in either FixedUpdate or Update, depending on where it makes more sense. If you want those inputs to feed into the physics engine, you would be well-advised to do that in FixedUpdate. But regardless of where you do it, it won't take effect until the next FixedUpdate and it won't become visible until the next rendered frame after that. This is simply a fact.

Comment: By the way, the last comment applies to the classic flag-oriented input system. I am not entirely sure when exactly the new event-oriented input system processes events.

Comment: Assuming that physics is fully synchronized with rendering, physics being earlier than update means that the motion caused by user input is completely ignored in current frame......while it would not be in another game loop. If Unity handles user input in fixedUpdate, I think that's one of the reasons why people call Unity a dumpster fire.

Comment: "I am not entirely sure when exactly the new event-oriented input system processes events" - it's up to the user now. [You can choose when you want input to be read](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4/manual/Settings.html#update-mode). "physics being earlier than update means that the motion caused by user input is completely ignored in current frame" - only if you follow the rule that you do not act on new input in `FixedUpdate`. Nobody requires you to follow such a rule - in fact, I actively advise against it in previous answers.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for the explanation. As far as I know, `FixedUpdate` mainly performs CPU-intensive tasks like physics simulation. If it also has to handle events, that seems too bad to me.

Comment: Input events are generally things you can count on one hand in any given time tick - there's just not that many buttons or axes a player could be interacting with all at once, even in local multiplayer. So it's not something that would make any meaningful CPU drain compared to integrating hundreds of physics bodies or the like.

Comment: @DMGregory Just because it works in practice doesn't mean it's right, and it's a shame that Unity users follow such practices.

Comment: I think you'll get a lot further if you focus more on making good games, and less on passing judgement against other developers.

Comment: @BlackGlory For someone who is "not familiar with Unity", you have pretty strong opinions about it and its users.

Comment: @Philipp The source of my strong opinion is what game development has always done: handle user input, update, and then physics. If Unity doesn't do it like that, then there has to be some reason. Unfortunately I haven't seen any convincing answers from the Unity folk. Sure, you Unity folk can say: "Yes, I handle everything in my `FixedUpdate`, it just works", which is okay on modern platforms, but that doesn't actually answer any questions. It just made things worse with the anti-pattern, and pretend things are right.

Comment: You're continuing to operate under the false assumption that Unity precludes handling input or running update logic before physics, which it does not in any way do. I'm sorry the engine is not to your taste, but that's not relevant to the question that you asked, and this site is not the venue to litigate which engines or game loops are implemented "right" or "wrong" in your opinion.